# Getting profile information with Google Sign-In on web app hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, authentication, web-applications, authorization, google-signin

I have a web app hosted on Azure for which I have enabled Google Sign-In under `Authentication / Authorisation` section of the settings of the app. I have tested it the app and can access it after signing in with my Google account - verified with couple of users, `authentication` works.

Next, I want to do `authorization` where I need to know the email of the logged in user - how can access the profile info of a user?

Documentation I have read so far:

1. To configure Google Sign-In I have used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google) documentationf rom
   Azure.
2. To create the sign in API credentials(client id and secret), I have
   used [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) documentation from Google. I am using OAuth2 and have
   set the type to Web Application.
3. I have done some research and I found out that I could get profile
   info using [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) example shown on the google documentation, but
   that is given I am implementing the Sign-In UI and code which comes
   with it, but in my case I have configured that in Azure and is an
   in-built feature.

Is there any way, I can access user profile information (email in my case) on the application without changing the authentication method keep using Azure's in built feature to add Google sign-In?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found that Microsoft provides some documentation on this and can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims).

More specifically, the email adress of the signed in user, which I was after can be fetched from header `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME`.